# How to G-ALT on Script? Logitech G213

Tags: logitech, logitech-gaming-software

Friend Egor Skriptunoff

```
`local function interruptable_sleep(delay)
   local tm = GetRunningTime() + delay
   repeat
      if IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock") then return true end
      local t = tm - GetRunningTime()
      if t > 0 then Sleep(math.min(t, 100)) end
   until t <= 0
end 
------------ TIPPLE SPOT-------------
function OnEvent(event, arg)
  if event=="G_PRESSED" and arg==1 then
      repeat
         local exit
         for _, phase in ipairs{
        {macro = "Pet1",     sleep_macro = 8000 },
                {macro = "Pop",   sleep_macro = 300,  },
                {macro = "Rush",     sleep_macro = 600,  },
                {macro = "MASS", sleep_macro = 4500, },
                {macro = "Pet2",     sleep_macro = 6500,  },
                {macro = "Pop",   sleep_macro = 300,  },
                {macro = "Rush",     sleep_macro = 600,  },
                {macro = "MASS", sleep_macro = 4500, },
                {macro = "Pet3",     sleep_macro = 7000,  },
                {macro = "Pop",   sleep_macro = 300,  },
                {macro = "Rush",     sleep_macro = 600,  },
                {macro = "MASS", sleep_macro = 4500, },
                
            
         } do
            PlayMacro(phase.macro)
            exit = interruptable_sleep(phase.sleep_macro)
            AbortMacro()
            if exit then break end
         end
      until exit
      Sleep(250)
      PressAndReleaseKey("scrolllock")

   end
end`
```

Long time ago you make this script for me , with i enjoy a lot with old Keyboard G105 i bought a new Keybpard g213 and G-keys or macro keys are from F1 to F12, but it do not work Please can tell me why? and How to make it work With G-ALT

Comment: What means `G-ALT` ?

Comment: G-alty it come on GHUB but not in LGS

Comment: I do have GHub.  But I don't know what G-Alt is.  I known only G-Shift.

Answer (score 0):

GHub has a bug/feature: `F1`-`F12` keys do not generate `G_PRESSED` events until you change their bindings to non-standard macros.
Workaround: to preserve standard function of `F1` key, just create your own macro "press `F1` - wait 50ms - Release `F1`" and assign it to physical `G1`/`F1` key.

Comment: Probleme is , if i make that the script will run multiple instances, the only way i could make it is on my mouse G402 bind key that swicht to G-ALT and bind script with an empty ,macro to F1/G1

Comment: `the script will run multiple instances` - How this may happen?

Comment: u tell me, i am a noob

Comment: How does it look when multiple instances are running?

Comment: ty for all , i think i will go back to my G105 , even LGS is better that GHUB